# R CMD check behaviour

Tags: c++, r

I am doing a package using R.3.1.2 and Rtools version 3.1.0.1942 on Windows 7.
I have some C++ source code that includes some headers files, specifically:
`#include<windows.h>`

I can compile and check it both with and without devtools.  I get no errors and no warnings. When I submit the package, however, it is rejected with the installation error:

```
fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory `#include<windows.h>`
```

The header file is in the Rtools and it is found easily on my PC.
I suppose the error is related to different Platform compilation. Can someone suggest a strategy to reproduce the error?. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain where are you submitting the package to?  This sounds like, yes some differences between your PC and someone else's, but nobody will be able to help you if you don't give more details.

Comment: @mjuarez `R CMD check` is an internal program which emulates building the package on the current machine prior to submitting to CRAN.  Other than checking for non-standard calls and the like, it shouldn't do anything different from direct compilation.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's bitching about the lack of whitespace between "include" and "<windows"

Comment: I submitted to the official Cran website.

Comment: The  suspect of Carl is similar to mine. i.e. maybe the choice between <windows.h> and "windows.h" can make the difference. I also read that after 1998 the ANSI rules is : <windows> instead of <windows.h>.  By the way, also the web service "win builder" doesn't show any error.